# Why is this an error?

Tags: java, syntax

I get an error on this line "System.out.println((num1/dem1)(num2/dem2)); "

The error says:

Multiple markers at this line
    - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
    - Syntax error on token ")", AssignmentOperator expected after 
     this token

```
package project;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class summerproject {
 public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
     Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
     {
    //INPUT NUMBERS
     System.out.println("Enter Numerator 1. ");
     int num1 = in.nextInt(); 
     System.out.println("Enter Denominator 1. ");
     int dem1 = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter Numerator 2. ");
     int num2 = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter Denominator 2. ");
     int den2 = in.nextInt();
     }
     System.out.println("Press 1 to multiply");
     int mult = in.nextInt();


     if (mult == 1)
     {
         System.out.println((num1/dem1)(num2/dem2));   
     }
    }//ARGS BRACKET      
 }//END BRACKET
```

Comment: Perhaps it is expecting an operator between values. Are you sure you're not trying to do something like `System.out.println((num1/dem1) + " " + (num2/dem2)); ` or as mattingly pointed out, * between them to multiply.

Answer (score 2):

This line isn't valid:

```
System.out.println((num1/dem1)(num2/dem2));
```

`(num1/dem1)` and `(num2/dem2)` need to have an operator between them.  For example, to multiply the two expressions together, use the `*` operator:

```
(num1/dem1)*(num2/dem2)
```

Java doesn't behave quite like mathematics, where concatenation implies multiplication.  Instead, you have to explicitly multiply operands together.

---

In addition, you declared

```
int den2 = in.nextInt();
```

This should be

```
int dem2 = in.nextInt().
```

---

After adjusting braces appropriately, and making the above fixes, you should end up with:

```
public class summerproject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //INPUT NUMBERS
        System.out.println("Enter Numerator 1. ");
        int num1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Denominator 1. ");
        int dem1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Numerator 2. ");
        int num2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Denominator 2. ");
        int dem2 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Press 1 to multiply");
        int mult = in.nextInt();

        if (mult == 1) {
            System.out.println((num1 / dem1) * (num2 / dem2));
        }
    }
}
```

---

An example run:

```
Enter Numerator 1. 
20
Enter Denominator 1. 
4
Enter Numerator 2. 
30
Enter Denominator 2. 
5
Press 1 to multiply
1
30
```

Comment: I dont think you can put ints in println, that might be the real issue. It needs a string

Comment: Pretty sure you can. println is heavily overloaded and I use that all the time on int testing

Comment: `System.out` is an instance of `PrintStream`, which has overloaded methods for printing the primitive types and objects.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html    Thus, printing ints is just fine.

Comment: I just tested @meda claim above to double check... you can in fact print an int

Comment: ok I did System.out.println((num1/dem1)*(num2/dem2)); however now they are not resolved as variables. if I declare them by saying          "int num1 = 0;" It doesn't work because you cant divide by 0.

Comment: Ok but that seems like a problem in your logic. It's up to you to avoid division by zero and declaring as proper types is the correct way to go

Comment: he also has extra set of brackets which places his variables out of scope

Comment: Updated for the brackets as well

Comment: also in addition to your recent edits, i might add that when he does system.out.print...he will get zero because he is not casting any of his numbers to a double

Comment: He will only get 0 if the numerator is smaller than the denominator, but yes, that is a caveat.

Answer (score 1):

You need an operator in the middle of your operations

Your code seems to indicate you want to multiply so try the code below instead...

```
System.out.println((num1/dem1)*(num2/dem2));
```